# How to get rid of devices in the left panel of Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, mount, automount, fstab

I would like to rid of not mounted ntfs partition from Nautilus' right panel ( I just want `352 GB Filesystem` - `d` drive to be there.

[image]

First of all `352 GB Filesystem` is in fact `d` so I do not know why it is duplicated.

Secondly I have put `Acer` and `SYSTEM RESERVED` to be `nouser` mounts on purpose, so that I (or sombody else) will not format it (or else) by accident.

So my `/etc/fstab` looks like this :

```
#comments.......
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
UUID=1384cee0-6a71-4b83-b0d3-1338db925168 /               ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=e3729117-b936-4c1d-9883-aee73dab6729 none            swap    sw              0       0
#------ MY WINDOWS D DRIVE----------
UUID=98E8B14DE8B12A80           /media/d    ntfs    defaults,errors=remount-ro,user 0   0
#
#-------ACER----------------
UUID=01CBEA9D4476C2F0           /media/acer ntfs    defaults,noauto,noexec,ro,nouser    0   0
#
#-------SYSTEM RESERVED-----
UUID=01CBEA95760F9330           /media/systemreserved   ntfs    defaults,noauto,noexec,ro,nouser    0   0
#UUID=58F9-C17E /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
```

`blkid` and `fdisk -l`

```
root@XXX:/home/YYY# fdisk -l
...
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            4096    27262975    13629440   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2        27262992    27467791      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        27467792   232267775   102399992    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       232267793   976771071   372251639+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       232267795   918867967   343300086+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6   *   918870016   968044543    24587264   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       968046592   976771071     4362240   82  Linux swap / Solaris
root@XXX:/home/YYY#  blkid 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="PQSERVICE" UUID="01CBEA95730D28A0" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="SYSTEM RESERVED" UUID="01CBEA95760F9330" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Acer" UUID="01CBEA9D4476C2F0" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="98E8B14DE8B12A80" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="1384cee0-6a71-4b83-b0d3-1338db925168" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="e3729117-b936-4c1d-9883-aee73dab6729" TYPE="swap"
```

Comment: You mean the left panel?

Comment: @LantzR Yes, of course - corrected.

Comment: similar: http://askubuntu.com/questions/122783/how-do-i-hide-remove-a-partition-from-the-nautilus-left-panel/775900#775900

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your fstab should look like this:

```
#comments.......
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
UUID=1384cee0-6a71-4b83-b0d3-1338db925168 /               ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=e3729117-b936-4c1d-9883-aee73dab6729 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

...no need to automount Windows recovery partitions, etc.

Now, to remove partitions from the left panel, create a udev rule:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/hide-partitions.rules
```

... and paste in the following:

```
ACTION!="add|change", GOTO="hide_partitions_end"
SUBSYSTEM!="block", GOTO="hide_partitions_end"
KERNEL=="loop*|ram*", GOTO="hide_partitions_end"

################################################## ############################

# Let's hide sda2 and sda3
KERNEL=="sda2", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
KERNEL=="sda3", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"

################################################## ############################

LABEL="hide_partitions_end"
```

...save and exit.

That should hide the "SYSTEM RESERVED" and "Acer" partitions after a reboot.