# Nautilus - sidebar menue/mounts - cannot unmount

Tags: nautilus

Can someone advise how to get-rid of the items that are on-the-side of this file manager (picture below)? Could you please advise where they are coming from?

The output of `ls -al /mnt` is:

```
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 20 23:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Sep 23 10:37 ..
```

The output of 'ls -al /media' is:

```
total 12
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Aug  4 12:23 .
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root 4096 Sep 23 10:37 ..
drwxr-x---+  2 root root 4096 Aug  4 15:49 maria
```

There is no '~/.config/nautilus/servers', as per below.

```
:~/.config/nautilus$ ls -lsa1
total 24
 4 drwxr-xr-x  2 maria maria 4096 Oct  4 15:37 .
 4 drwx------ 21 maria maria 4096 Oct  3 16:40 ..
12 -rw-r--r--  1 maria maria 9663 Oct  4 15:42 accels
 4 -rw-rw-r--  1 maria maria   96 Oct  4 15:37 desktop-metadata
```

Everything in '`/etc/fstab`' is commented-out.

[image]

Comment: They are presented to make it easy for you to click to mount them and then navigate the files. I've never wanted to blacklist mine but hopefully someone has an answer for you soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see on the left side of Nautilus are your partitions. Mounted ones have the eject button beside them, unmounted ones do not. To mount the partition click on the name. Then you can navigate the folders and files.

You want to hide partitions so they don't appear in Nautilus.

Start `Dash` the first option on the `Launcher`

Type `Open Disks` and you will see the application `Disks` appear. Click on it.

A screen similar to this appears:

[image: Open Disks]

Left click on a Disk. Then left click on the Partition you want to hide.

Right click on the double cog (follows the Left Arrow and `-`) and select `Edit Partition Options` and this screen appears:

[image]

Uncheck the option `Show in User Interface`.

Clock OK and enter password to apply changes. After the next reboot Nautilus won't show the partition. Note that this doesn't erase the partition or delete any data on it.

If you need clarification please post a comment below.

Comment: Hello. The following gives a great answer to part of the question:
"What you see on the left side of Nautilus are your partitions. Mounted ones have the eject button beside them, unmounted ones do not. "
I tried to navigate to the 'Mount Options' window, but this was not possible on my Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.  I clicked everywhere I could. I would like to have control of what can be seen in the User Interface.

Comment: As to the remaining part of the question, I understood that `/etc/fstab` contained _mounts_ which, when I commented-out, have disappeared from Nautilus.  And now, the remaining items that have remained there, are _partitions_.  It is challenging to understand the difference, and, also, I am needing to understand _shares_, and where those would appear.  Thank you so much for providing a good answer.

Comment: @user137810 Perhaps the best way of understanding is that `/etc/fstab` will mount partitions for you and `Nautilus` will also mount partitions for you. The solution above is to hide specific partitions in Nautilus via `User Interface` check box.

Comment: Oh that's great; so **_partitions_** _are_ **_mounted_**.  Well, my conclusion is that I had _mounts_ in `/etc/fstab`, and _mounts_ in `/home/maria/servers/`.  Is this the right name for things that are in `/home/maria/servers/`?  Last point.  Thank you.

Comment: In your case **things** in `/home/maria/servers/ are **mounted** but I have no such thing on my system. On my system `Android Phone` is mounted but on your system it isn't. Everyone names  **partitions** differently. To clarify my earlier comment `fstab` **automatically** mounts partitions, `Nautilus` gives you the **option** to mount them if `fstab` did not do it already. In `Nautilus` you can't use the eject button to unmount a partition in use.

Answer (score 0):

In Nautilus, go to the **Bookmarks** menu, and choose **Bookmarks...**, and there you can delete any of the bookmarks you desire.

Comment: Hi guys, no, what I mean is the mounts.  They are a long list above the 2 bookmarks at the bottom.  These have been umount ed.  But they are irrremovable from this nautilus window.

Comment: Which is not good.

Comment: What happens if you click the EJECT icon beside the name? Or right-click and choose remove/delete?  In terminal, what is the output of `ls -al /mnt` and `ls -al /media`? Cheers, Al

Comment: Maybe delete ~/.config/nautilus/servers? Cheers, Al

Comment: When I click the eject icon next to the ones that do have the eject icon displayed next to them, the following message appears: 'Unable to unmount “administration”.  umount: /home/maria/servers/zeus/administration: umount failed: Operation not permitted'.

Why do other ones have not the eject button displayed next to them?

The output of 'ls -al /mnt' is as follows:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 20 23:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Sep 23 10:37 ..

Comment: And 'ls -al /media' is as follows:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Aug  4 12:23 .
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root 4096 Sep 23 10:37 ..
drwxr-x---+  2 root root 4096 Aug  4 15:49 maria

I apologies for the mashed-together text, I tried Shift+Enter, but the line breaks are not picked up in Comments.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Edit your original question and add the ls commands. You'll be able to format them there. Also include `cat ~/.config/nautilus/servers`. Cheers, Al

Comment: Also see <`http://askubuntu.com/questions/122783/how-do-i-hide-remove-a-partition-from-the-nautilus-left-panel/775900#775900`>. Also add the output of  `cat /etc/fstab` to your question. Cheers, Al

Comment: And <`http://askubuntu.com/questions/181130/how-to-get-rid-of-devices-in-the-left-panel-of-nautilus?noredirect=1&lq=1`>. Cheers, Al

Comment: Hello Al - is there anything else I should do in terms of editing the question well?  Thanks.

Comment: /etc/fstab **can't** have everything commented out. From the new image that you posted, it looks like you've solved the problem, yes? All the extra mounts are gone. Did one of the URLs that I gave you help? If so, let me know which one, I can update my answer, and you can vote/accept it to close the question. Cheers, Al

Comment: Hi, when I commented-out 'paths' from `/etc/fstab`, yes, the items