# How to clear shortcuts to mounts?

Tags: mount, nautilus, disk-image

I was doing a lot of loopback mounts (mounting different disk image files). Each one is leaving a shortcut on the left pane of nautilus and on the Unity Launcher.

How to get rid of them without a restart?

[image: image mounts]

Comment: I never use loops, but with right click>remove doesn't it work? Is it greyed out?

Comment: @dadexix86,  grayed out.

Comment: And since they are not bookmarks, but partitions, you do not see them in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`. If they were disks, I would go with http://askubuntu.com/a/775900/29595 . Do they show up in Disks?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `mount`

Comment: @Velkan I believe that your case was not thought by the programmers of `nautilus`... Maybe you can [open a feature request](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=nautilus); I believe that the possibility to manipulate the shown devices directly will be useful for a lot of people.