# How to prevent a mount from displaying?

Tags: partitioning

I have a folder called `Programming` under my `/home` partition. I mounted a partition of 50gb under the `Programming` partition permanently. Everything works fine. But I don't want to visually show the mounted partition explicitly in the Ubuntu explorer(not sure what's the exact term). How do I achieve this?

[The partition in question is the highlighted one `Prog` . I don't want to display it.]

[image]

Comment: I assume you use gvfs and symlinks, to accomplish that; because drives mounted via `/etc/fstab` (normally) do not show in the sidepane of nautilus.

Comment: @db429 : I don't know what are they. I just added a entry in fstab - UUID=X-X-X-X-X  mountPoint    ext4          nodev,nosuid       0       2

Comment: hm, weired. pls edit your question and tell us what version of ubuntu/nautilus you use

Comment: @db429: 16.04 .

Comment: there is an `x-gvfs-hide` option for fstab as mentioned in one answer over here https://askubuntu.com/questions/122783/how-do-i-hide-remove-a-partition-from-the-nautilus-left-panel/775900#775900 ; might help