# No HDD device mount icons on Nautilus when run nautilus non root in Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver

Tags: mount, hard-drive, nautilus, icons, 18.04

I get no HDD device mount icons on Nautilus when running nautilus non-root in Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver. Any help in solving this?

I'll like to mount drives directly from nautilus sidebar (devices part). I noticed that if I ran nautilus root, it will show the hard drives and other devices on the devices list and I could mount and unmount them.

Answer (score 1):

The design has changed and you need to bookmark them first. You will probably want to rename the bookmark as well. This GIF illustrates the technique:

[image: Nautilus 18 bookmark.gif]

- From your "other locations" list pick a partition.
- Click the upper right "hamburger" menu.
- From the dropdown menu click the center menu button to bookmark it.
- Move to the new sidebar entry and rename it from the mount name ("c" in my example) to something more meaningful ("Windows 10 SSD" in my example).

Comment: Thank you for the tip! 

Are you sure they changed the design?  For me, bookmarking doesn't allow mounting or unmounting the partitions. If partition is not mounted before clicking the bookmark, the path is not found. Also, I noticed that if I ran the nautilus as root, only partitions in the fstab configuration would be visible in the devices list. Also, the partitions that are in the fstab are mounted to /mnt/ and others are mounted to /media/. But still nothing is visible when not root.

Comment: Yes only the mounted drives show up in Nautilus. The stuff in /media is user space objects that don't need sudo and generally auto mount when plugged in.

Comment: @LauriTK You can use the `disks` utility to tell Nautilus and all other GUI's to hide specific partitions from the user. This answer was for 16.04 but should give you a good idea how to set it up: https://askubuntu.com/questions/122783/how-do-i-hide-remove-a-partition-from-the-nautilus-left-panel/835040#835040

Comment: Thanks. For some reasons, it doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: @LauriTK Do you mean the `disks` utility doesn't let you reveal / hide mount points? You can also do the same in `/etc/fstab`. For example one of my  lines:  `UUID=5CCC5867CC583E08 /mnt/c ntfs-3g permissions,locale=en_US.utf8,x-gvfs-show`. This reveals on of my windows partition within **Nautiilus** side pane for me. The `gvfs-show` parameter enables the feature.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately the 'x-gvfs-show' doesn't seem to do anything. Could it be permission problem or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I changed the filemanager to the nemo, but I'am still interested at getting the nautilus working.